# merge objects and return condensed range object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm solving this problem:

> Write a function mergeRanges() that takes an array of meeting time
>   ranges and returns an array of condensed ranges (1 = 30 minutes)

```
Input:
[
    {startTime: 0,  endTime: 1}, // meeting from 10:00 – 10:30 am (1 = 30 minutes)
    {startTime: 3,  endTime: 5}, // meeting from 12:00 – 1:30 pm
    {startTime: 4,  endTime: 8},
    {startTime: 10, endTime: 12},
    {startTime: 9,  endTime: 10},
]

Expected Output: 

[
    {startTime: 0, endTime: 1},
    {startTime: 3, endTime: 8},
    {startTime: 9, endTime: 12},
]
```

My solution is/as follows:

```
var arr =   [
    {startTime: 0,  endTime: 1},
    {startTime: 3,  endTime: 5},
    {startTime: 4,  endTime: 8},
    {startTime: 10, endTime: 12},
    {startTime: 9,  endTime: 10},
];

function result(arr){
  var finalResult = {};

  var c = arr.sort(function(a,b){ //First Sort
    return a.startTime - b.startTime;
  });

  var d = c.reduce(function(a,b){

   //Logic

   //check to see if start time lies between a[start] < b[startTime] < a[end]

    // If the startTime lies between a[startTime] to b[endTime] -> Merge them.

// if(a[startTime]< b[startTime] < b[endTime]){ //if start time lies between start and end.
    //   a[endTime] = b[endTime];
    //   delete b;
    // }

  });

}

result(arr);
```

I'm not able to understand how to use reduce function to swap the logic. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: what do you mean by "swap the logic"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` and one variable to store endTime.

```js
var input = [
    {startTime: 0,  endTime: 1}, 
    {startTime: 3,  endTime: 5}, 
    {startTime: 4,  endTime: 8},
    {startTime: 10, endTime: 12},
    {startTime: 9,  endTime: 10},
]

var c = 0;
var result = input.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  //Check if c < startTime of current object in loop or if its first
  //element and if it is add it to r
  if (c < e.startTime || i == 0) {
    r.push(e)
  } else {
    //if not check if endTime of current object is > c 
    //(so you don't have problem at last object where endTime is smaller then some previous endTime) and change it
    //in r of last element that you added
    if (e.endTime > c) r[r.length - 1].endTime = e.endTime
  }
  //Always set c to current endTime
  c = e.endTime
  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: what is r, e and i ? (is i an index?) Why did you mark "C" as 0? Can you please explain your logic? I'm confused with your solution. (Sorry am very new to this reduce function.. recently started learning) @Nenad Vracar

Comment: Well `r` is accumulator or in this case its array, `e` is current object in loop, and `i` is index that you need just to check if its first element so you can add it to array.